# How to create an object to contain other objects

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Here is my code. Basically i'm trying to develop a way to store various things in local storage contained in an object called **myApp**

At the moment, I can save an object call **highscore** OK to local storage. I'm struggling to figure out how to place this **highscore** object with an object called **myApp** and save to local storage?

http://jsfiddle.net/judz9/

```
var localStorageClass = {
    set: function (key, value) {
        if (!key || !value) {
            return;
        }

        if (typeof value === "object") {
            value = JSON.stringify(value);
        }

        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    },
    get: function (key) {
        var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
        if (!value) {
            return;
        }
        if (value[0] === "{") {
            value = JSON.parse(value);
        }

        return value;
    }
};

var TestApp = {
    appLocalData: null,

    init: function () {
        this.appLocalData = localStorageClass;
    },
    setHighScore: function (game, score) {
        var hs = this.appLocalData.get('highscore');

        if (hs === undefined) {
            hs = {};
        }

        hs[game] = score;
        this.appLocalData.set('highscore', hs);
    },
    getHighScore: function (game) {
        var hs = this.appLocalData.get('highscore');
        return hs[game];
    }
};

TestApp.init();
TestApp.setHighScore('game1', 999);
console.log(localStorage);
```

Comment: localData is undefined

Comment: you need a to use a browser that supports local storage

Comment: The last line of your fiddle should be: console.log(localStorage);

Comment: I am, as Bitsplitter said, the last line should be localStorage, not localData.

Comment: Apologies you are correct. Question updated.

Comment: in your set and get methods within your app, pass the object you want to save (including myapp containing the highscore) as the value... i don't quite understand where the confusion is. `this.appLocalData.set("MyApp",{foo: {bar: {foo: "foobar!"}}})`

Comment: @KevinB the problem is that if I try to add a new object to foo, it overwrites the existing foo

Comment: Right, you've gotta pass the entire object every time. That or parse the existing object, extend it with the new object, then save that.

Comment: I need to create an object called highscores, that I can add and remove game scores from, this highscores object needs to sit with an object called MyApp. The reason is that MyApp will also have other objects such as user details, app settings etc. This is where i'm struggling as i'm not sure how to get and set the object each time

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to store all of your app data in local storage object with a key of 'MyApp'. I would go about achieving this by adding a `MyApp` object that will store all of the app data. `MyApp` will get initialized to the current local storage value of 'MyApp' or, if that is `null`, a new object. Whenver `MyApp` is altered, ie., when `localStorageClass.set` is called, the local storage will get updated to the current version of `MyApp`. I have used a closure for the initialization of `localStorageClass` so that I can keep `MyApp` effectively private.

```
var localStorageClass = (function () {
    var MyApp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('MyApp')) || {};

    return {
        set: function (key, value) {
            if (!key || !value) {
                return;
            }

            MyApp[key] = value;
            localStorage.setItem('MyApp', JSON.stringify(MyApp));
        },
        get: function (key) {
            return MyApp[key];
        }
    };
}());
```